# Is PHP $argv limited to 9 paramers on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, argv

Running the following script in PHP 5.5.4 CLI on Win7 32bit

```
php -r "print_r($argv);" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

I can see that only 8 arguments are actually parsed:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
)
```

Does Windows or PHP limit the number of command line args to 8/ total 9?

**Update:**

<strike>Works as expected on same PC with PHP 5.5.7 -> so at least on Win7 this is a PHP-specific problem.</strike>

The behaviour changes depending on if the script is run from the php folder or if php is found via path. A `procmon` trace seems to indicate that the problem is with Windows as- even before the PHP.exe image is being loaded- a different number of parameters is passed:

```
php.exe Process Start       SUCCESS Parent PID: 9088, Command line: "\Program Files\php\php"  -r "print_r($argv);" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, Current directory: C:\
php.exe Process Start       SUCCESS Parent PID: 9088, Command line: "\program files\php\php"  -r "print_r($argv);" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14, Current directory: C:\
php.exe Process Start       SUCCESS Parent PID: 9088, Command line: php  -r "print_r($argv);" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14, Current directory: C:\Program Files\php\
```

All parameters only seem to be available if PHP is NOT taken from the path.

Comment: Probably not. I think, the command line interpreter in windows, that is limited.

Comment: Shorter: Windows is limited. Good question tho!

Comment: Passing more than 8 parameters works fine for my PHP 5.4.12 installation on Windows, maybe it's a version thing. Which version are you on?

Answer (score 3):

Kind of, on some Windows environments.  To get more than 9 parameters on Windows XP you need to "shift" the parameters in your batch file.

I can't find any reference to this command on versions above XP, so it may be that this issue goes away with later versions of Windows.

A comment on PHP.NET covers it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#56846

> To pass more than 9 arguments to your php-script on Windows, you can
>   use the 'shift'-command in a batch file. After using 'shift', %1
>   becomes %0, %2 becomes %1 and so on - so you can fetch argument 10
>   etc.
>
> Here's an example - hopefully ready-to-use - batch file:
>
> **foo.bat:**

```
@echo off

:init_arg
set args=

:get_arg
shift
if "%0"=="" goto :finish_arg
set args=%args% %0 goto :get_arg

:finish_arg

set php=C:\path\to\php.exe
set ini=C:\path\to\php.ini
%php% -c %ini%
foo.php %args%
```

> Usage on commandline: foo -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -foo -bar
>
> A print_r($argv) will give you all of the passed arguments.

Comment: Do note that the comment is dated 8 years ago, so it is most likely somewhat outdated. I guess this behaviour depends on the user environment/PHP version, as running `C:\>php -r "print_r($argv);" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15` on my PHP 5.4.12 install on Win7 gives me all 15 parameters as a return value directly from the parser.

Comment: Agreed - I've been searching for more corroborating evidence (I'm running XP Professional here), and I can't find reference to the issue later than XP.  It is highly likely this issue does not exist in Windows 7 or 8. (answer updated to reflect) - @Oldskool - Win7? OldSkool?  Pah!

Comment: @Oldskool: very interesting. It doesn't do so for 5.5.4 on Win7 for me. 32bits?

Comment: @andig I'm on Win7 x64, so maybe 32/64 bits is the difference that causes this behaviour.